# nrf24l01+ works on channel 10 but not channel 82?

Tags: arduino, atmega, nrf24l01

Setup is nrf24l01+ with 328p running internal oscillator at 8Mhz.

I have been using it like this for a while with no problems at channel 10, but now want to change to a higher channel such as 82, but it does not work, why ?

Answer (score 2):

What it turned out to be was that I was running it off the internal 8Mhz oscillator... Even though there had been no problems at channel 10, running the higher frequency channel eg 82 could not.

So using either an external 8Mhz or 16Mhz crystal fixed the problem, likely caused by inaccuracies of the internal oscillator.

Comment: yeah, try not to run communications equipment on internal oscillators - ever. If you are doing super slow communications or just GPIO/PWM toggling then internal oscillators are good enough.

Comment: Communication with that chip uses SPI. Did you run it near the maximum frequency? Otherwise I very much doubt that the inaccuracy of the internal oscillator was your real problem.

Comment: Do you mean max frequency of spi or nrf24?